# permission script with stat command trouble awk special character

Tags: linux, permissions, grep, awk, stat

I want to number of permission directory and write a script for equalizing two different server directory. I have use stat command.

command: `stat /var/ | grep -i 'Access: ('`

output: `Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)`

I want to only 755 which my command output. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
stat --printf "%a" /var
```

Output:

```
755
```

---

See: `man stat`

Comment: Note: to parse further `"%a\n"` may be better. In POSIX a line without a newline character at the end is incomplete and some tools may omit it.